# Multiple instances or processes of Visual Studio Code in task manager for single application window

Tags: process, visual-studio-code, process-management

I'm using Visual Studio Code. I'm facing a performance issue on my machine. I went to task manager and saw that there are several instances of **Code.exe** in the process tab even though there is *only* one window of Visual Studio Code running/active on my PC.

[image: Multiple Visual Studio Code exe instances in process tab]

I can see that in all there are eight instances of **Code.exe**. Although, I can see that all eight instances are taking RAM memory in the range of few KBs to a maximum of 55 MB. So one thing was sure that these few processes are not eating up too much memory together but still their count stumbled me for a second. I had an understanding that one Visual Studio Code window should map to a single **Code.exe** process.

I've one more observation. I opened another fresh window of Visual Studio Code and saw that the count of **Code.exe** processes increased by two instead of one this time. Total **Code.exe** process count now became 10 on its own when a total of 2 Visual Studio Code windows are currently active. I'm not sure what's going on in here. Can someone help me understand if this is the right behavior on how Visual Studio Code is implemented internally?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior is by Design and is documented in the comments in the Github Issues [#5856](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5856), [#8006](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8006) and [#20856](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20856)

Summary from the comments mentioned in the Links

> This behavior is a consequence of both how vscode was designed and the
>   fact that it's build on Chromium/Electron. The number of processes
>   should not really matter from an end user perspective, it's the amount
>   of work each process does and the communication between them that are
>   important.
>
> By design, the UI framework we use is multi process by itself and then
>   we have 1 process for extensions (per window), one process for file
>   watching (per window) and 1 process for search. We also have 1 shared
>   process for updates.

Using a Tool like Process Explorer, You can get more details about the Process.
Only one of the Process `code.exe` would have the parent as `explorer.exe` which denotes the Main Process which spawned other Children Processes. Following is a screenshot of how the Main `code.exe` properties appears using the Tool **Process Explorer**.

[image]

Additionally, a quick glance at the command line arguments for each of the Children `code.exe` process would provide more useful information as to what each process is supposed to do. For e.g. one of the Child process `code.exe` seems to be an error Reporting Process for crashes.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --reporter-url=https://ticinocrashreporter.azurewebsites.net/crash --application-name=VSCode "--crashes-directory=..\AppData\Local\Temp\VSCode Crashes" --v=1
```

Comment: Interestingly when I looked at the properties of main `code.exe` process (parent of other `code.exe` processes) in process explorer, it shows its parent as `<Non-existent Process>(5188)`. I checked the process explorer and task manager both but there is no explorer process running with PID 5188. Does windows play some trick to keep such `explorer.exe` process hidden from the user. I can see another `explorer.exe` process with a different PID 3056 though. Does window maintains multiple/several `explorer.exe` processes meant for different purposes?

Comment: Same exe can be run under different user accounts. Windows can have multiple `explorer.exe` running under different user accounts.

Comment: What a terrible design!  These should be threads, not full Windows processes.

Answer (score 2):

Well I too just figured out that issue in my task manager. My case it is 6 instances. It was a lot more previously but once I cleared the recent project list in **File > Open Recent**, the number came down to 6.

Now the mystery of 6 was also resolved. The extra instances in task manager are used for the 'Extensions', 'Code editor' etc. windows / views inside VS Code.

You can verify this by killing one by one other instances in the task manager, as you do that the VS Code will start showing error and will complain about the instances that we are killing in task manager.

Hope it helps.