# Visual Studio Code: Another instance of Code is running but not responding

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can't run Visual Studio Code (Windows). This happend a few times now.

I suddenly can't save files while coding and VS Code hanging. When stopping the task by Task Manager

[image]

and start VS Code again I get the message:

> Another instance of Code is running but not responding. Please close all other instances and try again.

[image]

But there is no VS Code Window open. Instead the Task Manager shows more running instances:

[image]

Restarting windows helps but is really annoying. Has anyone else this problem and/or an idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try ending the task from within Task Manager?

Comment: Killing Task within Task Manager was the first thing I did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816178/multiple-instances-or-processes-of-visual-studio-code-in-task-manager-for-single describes the listet instances as subprocesses or addons in VS Code. Anyway, "not responding" is still mysterious.

Comment: I get the same message, if I opened too many files at the same time, using FileZilla.

Comment: @Toni Today again the same error with VS Code. I could not start FileZilla during this either.

Answer (score 5):

I tried everything: restarting Windows, uninstalling and reinstalling VSC, nothing helped.
There should be something in the "memory of the last session". And I found it:

Finally, I renamed / deleted the following file to make it not available:

- Folder `%AppData%\Code`
- File `storage.json`

Now I was able to restart VSC, forcing a clean startup. The file was recreated. Now I could search which content of this file was the reason.

Comment: What happens to unsaved files?

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Unfortunately, the `%AppData%\Code\package.json` does not exist for me.

Comment: @ztom He suggests to delete  `%AppData%\Code` and the file `storage.json`.

So  no need to do something with `package.json`.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I meant storage.json.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

Restart OS fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I have already mentioned this in the question. Restarting windows helps but is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

**My experience with fbprophet:**

**Problem:**

The code below kept crashing VS and giving me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnXHb.png).
I then clicked Reopen. Nothing happened. Tried to open VS code again and got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAr2z.png) .

```
m = prophet.Prophet(interval_width=0.95, daily_seasonality=True)
model = m.fit(data)
```

**Solution:**

Restarted my computer and
Filtered `data` to only contain the date and the y column.

I'm guessing the part of this that would be relevant to others is to find what is crashing VS code and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following cmd.
It's effective with my centos7.

```
$ ps -ef | grep code | grep -v grep | cut -c 9-15 | xargs kill -s 9
```

Comment: Basically, it will shut down all the processing of VS Code.
And you can edit the file with code by inputting the following cmd: 

code your_file_path --user-data-dir

Answer (score 0):

there is a closed [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162429) on vscode GitHub page about this topic. It looks like the bug can't be resolved. but try to kill the process from the task manager and now you can open a new vscode window.

Comment: I'll update this answer if I find any possible solution.